# Saving video to public folder using android default folders does not appear in Gallery

Tags: android, android-gallery

I am saving a video to public folder using

```
 private File createVideoFile(){
        if(!isExternalStorageWritable()){
            return null;
        }
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "vid121.mp4");

        return file;
    }
```

However I tried also PICTURES, and VIDEOS 
and no matter what folder I try, the video does not appear when the user opens default gallery app (or even any app that shows videos). I navigated to the folder through Files app and I can see the video.

How can I make sure the video appears as part of gallery?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rescan gallery. Because Gallery refreshed by default at boot time.

Try this.

```
// Tell the media scanner about the new file so that it is
// immediately available to the user.
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
        new String[] { file.toString() }, null,
        new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
        Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
        Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
    }
});
```